# Baffling conflict with multiple nuget packages: System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.IChangeToken'

Tags: .net-core, nunit, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I've encountered a really strange conflict between multiple nuget packages that don't make sense to me, and I've been struggling to solve it. I'll offer a bounty as I've spent days on this. The full error:

> System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.IChangeToken Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration.GetReloadToken()'.

I'm using two different nuget packages together: [Any-Config](https://github.com/replaysMike/AnyConfig) (config library) and [NUnit.Extensions.TestMonitor](https://github.com/replaysMike/NUnit.Extension.TestMonitor) (nunit extension for realtime test monitoring), which are unrelated to each other. Any-Config has a full implementation for IConfiguration. Everything works fine on their own, but when I try to use them in a net5 project that reference both [SignalR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client) and using a FrameworkReference of `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` in the project this error is thrown and it's baffling how this could be happening. I suspect some framework voodoo but I really don't know at this point.

If I remove either the `SignalR` nuget package -or- the FrameworkReference everything works fine. Here's the full repro project:

UnitTest1.cs:

```
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var value = AnyConfig.Config.Get<bool>("TestBool");
        Assert.AreEqual(true, value);
    }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "TestBool": true
}
```

TestProject.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- comment out SignalR package and everything works -->
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="5.0.11" />
        <!-- -->

        <PackageReference Include="Any-Config" Version="1.0.155" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Extension.TestMonitor" Version="1.0.51" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.16.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="appsettings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I'm not sure how either of those scenarios can suddenly make the implementation disappear when called - purely by referencing the packages. If I try and step through Any-Config in the debugger, it breaks at unexpected places in the code and the debugger seems confused.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this after almost a week of heartache - the NUnit.Extension.TestMonitor package references NUnit.Engine 3.12 which was causing the issue. It works fine if downgraded to NUnit.Engine 3.11, so I'll have to report this to them and see what was changed that could have caused this very weird issue!

Updated repro source that only uses NUnit.Engine to trigger the issue:

UnitTest1.cs:

```
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var value = AnyConfig.Config.Get<bool>("TestBool");
        Assert.AreEqual(true, value);
    }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "TestBool": true
}
```

TestProject.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- comment out SignalR package and everything works -->
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="5.0.11" />
        <!-- -->

        <PackageReference Include="Any-Config" Version="1.0.155" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Engine" Version="3.12.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.16.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="appsettings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```